# cannot delete keyframe, seems to be unattached to any object

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm making an animation in blender using some vrms I imported from vroid. I'm trying to delete a keyframe, that keyframe appears in the animations timeline and the top of the dope sheet. But if you scroll down the dope sheet this keyframe corresponds to no keyframe on any object, also there is no keyframe in the action editor either.

[image]

There is nothing anywhere else in this animation, just the hand and arm moving right there which I have pointed to with the red lines.

below is the same animation viewed in the timeline (incase that is helpful).
[image]

1. How can I delete that last frame?
2. What are the highlighted frames at the beginning and end?

### edit

extra info

The keyframes I cannot delete are always yellow. They always appear to be selected and I can't seem to deselect them. They also cannot be moved or copied.

Comment: I had a similair issue before. For me there were two possibilities: 1) You might want to check if your bones have values that are locked by finding the bones that are keyframed, using the drop-down-menu on the left. Or 2) The rig object itself has values that are keyframed: Like location or other settings. Just a guess.

Comment: can you add a blend file that shows the problem to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Answer (score 0):

Try tabbing into object mode, selecting your armature/rig and press 'alt+i' on your keyboard and press the 'delete keyframe' option.

This might solve your issue

Comment: didnt do anything, thank you though :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else stumbles upon that quite misleading UI behavior (always selected summary keyframes without any actual object keyframes visible):
In my case, there where keyframes for hidden objects and the `show hidden` button made them accessible.
The `show hidden` button is located between the `only show selected` button labeled with a mouse pointer and the `only show errors` button labeled with an exclamation triangle.
All keyframes should be visible when only the `show hidden` button is on and the other two are off.